# After saving canvas, picture not available

Tags: android, canvas

I am trying to save the state of my canvas to my SD card or just phone gallery, it doesn't really matter to me. Ihave these code below, and when screen is clicked a file is saved in SD card but as an unrecognized file, like a exclamation warning mark pic is unavailable

Code:

```
package your.save.namespace; 
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import java.io.FileOutputStream; 
import android.content.Context; 
import android.graphics.Bitmap; 
import android.graphics.Canvas; 
import android.graphics.Color; 
import android.graphics.Paint; 
import android.util.Log; 
import android.view.KeyEvent; 
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View; 
import android.widget.Toast;
public class testSaveView extends Activity 
{ 
        SomeView sv = null; 
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */ 
    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        sv = new SomeView(this); 
        setContentView( sv ); 
    } 
    @Override 
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
    {
     int type=event.getAction();
     Log.i(null,"GOOOD");
     if(type==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        { 

                        if ( sv != null ) 
                        { 
                              Log.i(null,"GOOOD");
                                saveView( sv ); 
                                return true; 

                        } 
                        Log.i(null,"GOOOD");
        }
     return true;
     }
    private void saveView( View view ) 
    { 
         Log.i(null,"GOOOD");
         Log.i(null,"hii"+view.getWidth()+"hello"+view.getHeight ());
       Bitmap  b = Bitmap.createBitmap( view.getWidth(), view.getHeight (), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); 
       Canvas c = new Canvas( b ); 
       view.draw( c ); 
       FileOutputStream fos = null; 
       try { 
                fos = new FileOutputStream( "/sdcard/some_view_image_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png" ); 
                Toast.makeText( null, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.i(null,"GOOOD");

                if ( fos != null ) 
                { 
                    Log.i(null,"GOOOD!!!!!!!");

                        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos ); 
                        fos.close(); 
                } 
                setWallpaper( b ); 
            } catch( Exception e ) 
                        { 
                        Log.e("testSaveView", "Exception: " + e.toString() ); 
                        } 
    } 
class SomeView extends View 
{ 
        public SomeView( Context context ) 
        { 
          super( context ); 
        } 
        public void onDraw( Canvas canvas ) 
        { 
                canvas.drawARGB(0x80, 0xff, 0, 0 ); 
                Paint paint = new Paint(); 
                paint.setColor(Color.BLUE); 
                paint.setTextSize( 48 ); 
                canvas.drawText("...Some view...", 10, canvas.getHeight() / 2, 
paint); 
        } 
} 
}
```

Maybe the problem is on manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="your.save.namespace"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
           <activity android:name=".testSaveView" 
                  android:label="@string/app_name"> 
            <intent-filter> 
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
                <category 
android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 
            </intent-filter> 
        </activity> 
    </application> 
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"></uses-permission> 
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-sdk > repeat 2 times 3 & 10 remove any 1
```

for accessing SD card you need uses permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```